# Is it possible to disable ion-scroll for specific screen size/device?

Tags: ionic-framework

if it's possible to disable ion-scroll for some devices (eg. iPhone 6).

Comment: I imagine you would have to do it with CSS - maybe an `ng-class` but you would have to figure out what CSS to apply by either inspecting a build through Safari, or investigating the `ion-scroll` directive

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with the $ionicScrollDelegate http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/service/$ionicScrollDelegate/ 
freezeAllScrolls method under the condition you need:

```
    //Using screen size
    var screenSize = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 375px)").matches;
    $ionicScrollDelegate.freezeAllScrolls(screenSize);

    //Using ionic classes
    var ios7 = document.body.classList.contains('platform-ios7');
    $ionicScrollDelegate.freezeAllScrolls(ios7);
```